# bind() inside of class vs bind inside of "classic" object

Tags: javascript

I have two object declarations. One is without using class and the second one is created by class. I know that I have to use bind() in the first's one print method to refer to object array as setTimeout method refers to window so I need to change the context of "this" keyword. My question is why in the second one I don't use bind() and the result is exact same?

```
let obj = {
    time: 2000,
    array: ["cat", "dog", "tortoise", "bat"],
    print: function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.array.forEach(el => console.log(el.toUpperCase()));
        }.bind(this), this.time);
    }
}

obj.print();

class Obj {
    constructor(){
        this.time = 2000;
        this.array = ["cat", "dog", "tortoise", "bat"];
    }

    print(){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.array.forEach(el => console.log(el.toUpperCase()));
        }, this.time);
    }
}

let o = new Obj();
o.print();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, in the second (class) object, you use an `arrow` function that binds the `this` to it's lexical scope (the class `Obj`), rather than the traditional function that binds the `this` to the call-site (where the function was called from).